# I am not able to see controlbar on ooyala player

Tags: javascript, ooyala

This is my current setup

```
<script src="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.33.25/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.33.25/video-plugin/bit_wrapper.min.js"></script>
<script src="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.33.25/video-plugin/main_html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.20.8/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js"></script>
<script src="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.33.25/video-plugin/osmf_flash.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.20.8/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.css"/>
```

Video works and control-bar is shown, but i cannot view the video in full screen on Chrome.

I am exactly facing this issue mentioned in the [link](http://community.ooyala.com/t5/Ooyala-Player-V4-Forum/Fullscreen-Errors-in-Chrome-71/td-p/10987)

I followed the reply from the thread and 
and updated all links with `/v4/production/latest/`

Video Works but Control-bar is no longer visible.

What must have went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For now i have solved my issue by setting `/v4/stable/4.31.17/` for `skin.json` . Also, i removed `html5-skin.min.js` from my project. which solves my issue of control bar. (i.e. now i can see control bar like the way it was before. Also, i can now toggle the video full screen on chrome. Thats the reason why i updated the player )

If i include html5-skin > `/v4/stable/4.20.8/` It throws some weird react error in the console like this.

error :

```
react-dom.production.min.js:13 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #188; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=188 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:524946
    at V (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:525049)
    at http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:548897
    at on (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:548934)
    at Object.findDOMNode (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:614892)
    at r.generateResponsiveData (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:325337)
    at r.onResize (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:325157)
    at n (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:513587)
    at g (http://player.ooyala.com/static/v4/stable/4.31.17/skin-plugin/html5-skin.min.js:1:513657
```

Chrome version Used : 75